# Unsetting cookies and sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to unset the cookie and session but can't.
My Code

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["SRAUSERNAME"]);
unset($_SESSION["SRAPASSWORD"]);
unset($_COOKIE["RAUSERNAME"]);
unset($_COOKIE["RAPASSWORD"]);
setcookie("RAUSERNAME","",time() -60*60);
setcookie("RAPASSWORD","",time() -60*60);
header("location: ../");
?>
```

The Sessions has been unset-ted but cookies is not. Why?

Comment: Tried first session_start()?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: They mean that before you can work with the session _in any way_, you first need to _start_ it. You can not unset session values, if you don't have a session to begin with - and until you call session_start, you don't. And instead of unsetting each session value individually, use session_destroy.

Comment: did you start the session? and do the session arrays have value?

Comment: You have to start session before you can use it. But I don't think that is the problem. Please provide more details.

Comment: **what you're doing now is totally unsafe.**

Comment: Started sessions.

Comment: Not resolved yet

Comment: What does print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: The session has been removed but the cookie isn't.